# Is there a link between margarita cocktail and margherita pizza?

Tags: etymology, differences, food

They sound the same, but is there any link between margarita cocktail and margherita pizza?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please demonstrate the research you have attempted, such as looking up the etymology of *margarita* in a dictionary. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster I answered my own question, does that count?

Comment: Since the three close votes that this question has received to this point were for lack of research, the fact that the poster did enough research to support a fairly complete (and well-supported) answer ought at least remove "lack of research" from the reasons to close it, in my opinion.

Comment: @rybo111 - Putting "answered own question" in the question sounds like irrelevant chat, so I've removed it.

Comment: @AndyT Seems fair. Just not sure how else to address the suggestion that it's "off-topic".

Comment: @rybo111 - If it's easily googlable, it's off-topic. If it's not easily googlable, and took you 10 minutes to research, then put the 5 second google results in the question. But I was able to make an educated guess at the correct answer without any googling at all, so it seems an overly simple question to me.

Comment: @AndyT Sure it's easily Googleable, because this page is the first result for `margarita cocktail and margherita pizza` ;)

Answer (score 4):

[Raffaele Esposito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raffaele_Esposito) is said to have [named margherita pizza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_pizza#Innovation) after [Queen Margherita of Savoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margherita_of_Savoy), although [research suggests this legend may be false](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/0/20515123).

The margarita cocktail, however, has [a number of stories regarding its origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Margarita#Origin), including being named after:

- Marjorie King
- Margarita Henkel
- Margarita Sames
- Peggy (Margaret) Lee
- An American drink called Tequila Daisy (Margarita is Spanish for Daisy)

The only apparent link here is that they both derive from the Spanish & Italian equivalents of the name [Margaret](http://www.behindthename.com/name/margaret).

Comment: The last proposal for the margarita cocktail seems to be the good one. The "Daisy" is a cocktail with Brandy. During Prohibition, the Brandy was replaced by Tequila in the Mexican bars located near the border.